# Finding coordinate of control point in Bezier Quadratic Curve

Tags: geometry, bezier-curve

I have both the endpoints of the Bezier Curve also I know the length of the curve and x' coordinate of the control point. So how can I find the y' coordinate of the control point?

I went through control polygon length approach of this [link](https://raphlinus.github.io/curves/2018/12/28/bezier-arclength.html) but solving it results into quartic equation which makes it difficult to find roots since I am trying to implement this in my code.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgE5e.jpg)

Comment: From a programming perspective, this is not necessarily a problem as there are formulas for roots of a general quartic polynomial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots So with a few new variables and ifs, you can be on your way. Of course, this does not mean there are not simpler ways to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Your reference [How long is that Bézier?](https://raphlinus.github.io/curves/2018/12/28/bezier-arclength.html) has a link to [A Primer on Bézier Curves](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#arclength), where they find an *explicit* expression for the arc length of a quadratic Bézier.
Turn this into a function of $y'$ and use numerical methods such as binary search to find one of the solutions.

As starting points for a binary search, picking $y'$ such that the control point is collinear with the endpoints should result in a *too short* curve (at least if $x'$ is between $x_1$ and $x_2$), and by a simple estimate (using the polygonal bound after one subdivision) says that 
$$ y'=2\ell-\frac32|y_2-y_1|+\max\{y_1,y_2\}=2\ell-\frac12|y_2-y_1|+\min\{y_1,y_2\}$$
is a feasible initial choice for $y'$ that makes the curve *too long*.

---

Of course if you already reduced the problem to finding a root of a quartic, you can also take that as a starting point for a *numerical* search for a root (e.g., by Newton's method).

Answer (score 0):

Simplistic approach.

[image]

Let the arc length of the quadratic Bezier segment 
$\operatorname{Bez_2}(A,B,C)$
with control points $A,B,C$ be $L$.

The points of the Bezier segment are found as
\begin{align} 
P(t)=(P_x(t),P_y(t))
,\\
P_x(t)&=
A_x\,(1-t)^2+2\,B_x(1-t)t+C_x\,t^2
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
P_y(t)&=
A_y\,(1-t)^2+2\,B_y(1-t)t+C_y\,t^2
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Given $A,C$ and $B_x$,
we can find $t=t_x$ from \eqref{1},
and \eqref{2} will provide the relation 
between the $y$-coordinate of the point on the segment
with given $x=B_x$, and corresponding value 
of the $y$-coordinate of the control point.

Consider an ellipse with the foci at $A,C$,
which intersects the line $x=B_x$ at the points $E$ and $F$,

\begin{align} 
|AE|+|CE|&=|AF|+|CF|=L
.
\end{align}

These points define the range $B_{\max}B_{\min}$
on the line $x=B_x$, where the control point $B$
must be located in order to get the arc length $L$
of the Bezier segment.

So, we can choose any point 
\begin{align} 
B_t&=B_{\max}(1-t)+B_{\min}\,t
,\quad t\in[0,1]
\end{align}
in that range,
find corresponding control point $B_{\mathrm{mid}}$
and check if the segment 
$\operatorname{Bez_2}(A,B_{\mathrm{mid}},C)$
has the length $L$ withing a suitable error range.

In general, there are two control points, $B_1$ and $B_2$,
separated by the line through $A,C$,
that produce two different quadratic Bezier segments
with the same arc length $L$.